# How to add submit button in a form row and print the data on student side

Tags: php, html, forms

I am creating an online web-based grading system and I am having a difficult time adding a submit button on every row after each grade. So far, my code only allows me to post the grade on the student side of the portal once the first and second quarter grades are complete. I wanted to post the grades every quarter in line with the mandate of the school.

Here is the code that I used so far:

```
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $learnerCount++; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo htmlentities($learner->StudLastName); ?>,&nbsp;<?php echo htmlentities($learner->StudFirstName); ?>&nbsp;<?php echo htmlentities($learner->StudMiddleName); ?></td>
                <?php
                // print out Grades for the selected Quarter
                $semGradeCount = 0;
                $semesterGrade = 0;
                foreach ($learnerGrades as $learnerGrade) {
                    if ($advising->Semester == 1) {
                        if ($learnerGrade->Quarter == 1) {
                            echo "<td  >$learnerGrade->Result</td>";
                            $semGradeCount++;
                            $semesterGrade += $learnerGrade->Result;
                        } else if ($learnerGrade->Quarter == 2) {
                            echo "<td  >$learnerGrade->Result</td>";
                            $semGradeCount++;
                            $semesterGrade += $learnerGrade->Result;
                        }
                    } else if ($advising->Semester == 2) {
                        if ($learnerGrade->Quarter == 3) {
                            echo "<td  >$learnerGrade->Result</td>";
                            $semGradeCount++;
                            $semesterGrade += $learnerGrade->Result;
                        } else if ($learnerGrade->Quarter == 4) {
                            echo "<td  >$learnerGrade->Result</td>";
                            $semGradeCount++;
                            $semesterGrade += $learnerGrade->Result;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if ($semGradeCount != 2) {
                    for ($i = $semGradeCount + 1; $i <= 2; $i++) {
                        echo "<td>-</td>";
                    }
                }
                if ($semGradeCount == 2) {
                    $finalGrade = $semesterGrade / 2;
                    $finalGradeQuery = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM tblgrades WHERE StudentId=:studentid AND AdvisingId=:advisingid AND Quarter=5");
                    $finalGradeQuery->bindParam(":studentid", $learner->id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                    $finalGradeQuery->bindParam(":advisingid", $advising->id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                    $finalGradeQuery->execute();
                    if ($finalGradeQuery->rowCount() == 1) {
                        $finalGradeRes = $finalGradeQuery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
                        if ($finalGrade != $finalGradeRes->Result) {
                            echo "<form method='POST'><input type='hidden' name='gradeId' value='$finalGradeRes->id'></input><input type='hidden' name='finalGrade' value='$finalGrade'></input><td>$finalGrade &nbsp;<button class='btn btn-success btn-sm' type='submit' name='repostFinalGrade' data-bs-toggle='tooltip' data-bs-placement='top' title='Post Updated Final Grade'>Submit</button></td></form>";
                        } else {
                            echo "<td>$finalGrade</td>";
                        }
                    } else {
                        echo "<form method='POST'><input type='hidden' name='studentId' value='$learner->id'></input><input type='hidden' name='advisingId' value='$advisingId'></input><input type='hidden' name='finalGrade' value='$finalGrade'></input><td > $finalGrade &nbsp;<button class='btn btn-success btn-sm' type='submit' name='postFinalGrade' data-bs-toggle='tooltip' data-bs-placement='top' title='Post Final Grade'>Submit</button></td></form>";
                    }
                    if ($finalGrade >= 75) {
                        echo "<td><b>PASSED</b></td>";
                    } else echo "<td><b>FAILED</b></td>";
                } else {
                    echo "<td>-</td>";
                    echo "<td>-</td>";
                }
                ?>
            </tr>
```

Comment: Can I just suggest to abstract the code a bit, create a function/method that handles "semester" (any). If you further separate your logic and presentation (PHP from HTML), it will make it so much easier to understand what's happening and how to implement functionality.

Comment: you need to do few things, 1) provide each submit button unique id, 2) provide each row or at least columns in that row which are getting submit on that button unique id, 3) do it with ajax, if you don't want to reload everytime